# Spark: foreachPartition Task not serializable

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, lucene

As per the tile I am getting `Task not serializable` at `foreachPartition`. Below the code snippet:

```
documents.repartition(1).foreachPartition( allDocuments => {

  val luceneIndexWriter: IndexWriter = getIndexWriter(localLuceneIndexDirPath)
  val protosCache = Files.newOutputStream(Paths.get(s"${localLuceneIndexDirPath}/${PROTOS_CACHE_FILE}"))
  val protosMdFile = Files.newOutputStream(Paths.get(s"${localLuceneIndexDirPath}/${PROTOS_MD_FILE}"))
  val DOCID: AtomicInteger = new AtomicInteger(1)
  val umcIdsCache = new mutable.ListBuffer[String] 

  allDocuments.foreach ( row => {
  .....
  })
  luceneIndexWriter.commit()
  luceneIndexWriter.close()
})
```

I am iterating through each doc and generating the lucene index. My guess is the different writers declared are not serializable and hence the exception. But the writers are defined for each partition and hence should not complain. Any thoughts?

Edit2:
Added `extends Serializable` and now facing the below error:

```
21/11/12 18:35:23 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 3, cmdata0804.usmsc23.pie.com, executor 1): java.io.InvalidClassException: com.science.video.indexer.LuceneIndexerJob$; no valid constructor
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$ExceptionInfo.newInvalidClassException(ObjectStreamClass.java:169)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.checkDeserialize(ObjectStreamClass.java:874)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2043)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2287)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2211)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2287)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2211)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2287)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2211)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2287)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2211)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:83)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$11.apply(Executor.scala:407)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:413)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
21/11/12 18:35:23 INFO cluster.YarnClusterScheduler: Removed
TaskSet 2.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
21/11/12 18:35:23 INFO cluster.YarnClusterScheduler: Cancelling
stage 2
21/11/12 18:35:23 INFO cluster.YarnClusterScheduler: Killing all running tasks in stage 2: Stage cancelled
21/11/12 18:35:23 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: ResultStage 2 (foreachPartition at LuceneIndexerHelper.scala:94) failed in 0.693 s due to Job aborted due to stage failure: 
Aborting TaskSet 2.0 because task 0 (partition 0)
cannot run anywhere due to node and executor blacklist.
```

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace?

Comment: @EmilianoMartinez added stack trace

Comment: Solved the issue. Had defined it as trait , changing it to object.